# filtering user input in php

Tags: filter, filtering, sanitize, sanitization

Am wondering if the combination of trim(), strip_tags() and addslashes() is enough to filter values of variables from $_GET and $_POST

Comment: It depends on what you are doing with your GET and POST values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends what kind of validation you are wanting to perform.

Here are some basic examples:

- If the data is going to be used in MySQL queries make sure to use mysql_real_escape_query() on the data instead of addslashes().
- If it contains file paths be sure to remove the "../" parts and block access to sensitive filename.
- If you are going to display the data on a web page, make sure to use htmlspecialchars() on it.

But the most important validation is only accepting the values you are expecting, in other words: only allow numeric values when you are expecting numbers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: it depends.

Basically you can't say that a certain amount of filtering is or isn't sufficient without considering what you want to do with it. For example, the above will allow through "javascript:dostuff();", which might be OK or it might not if you happen to use one of those GET or POST values in the href attribute of a link.

Likewise you might have a rich text area where users can edit so stripping tags out of that doesn't exactly make sense.

I guess what I'm trying to say is that there is simple set of steps to sanitizing your data such that you can cross it off and say "done". You always have to consider what that data is doing.

Answer (score 1):

It highly depends where you are going to use it for.

- If you are going to display things as HTML, make absolutely sure you are properly specifying the encoding (e.g.: UTF-8). As long as you strip all tags, you **should** be fine.
- For use in SQL queries, addslashes is not enough! If you use the mysqli library for example, you want to look at [mysql::real_escape_string](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). For other DB libraries, use the designated escape function!
- If you are going to use the string in javascript, addslashes **will not** be enough.
- If you are paranoid about browser bugs, check out the [OWASP Reform library](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Encoding_Project)
- If you use the data in another context than HTML, other escaping techniques apply.